# Clojure - Autoupdating Listbox

Tags: clojure, listbox, seesaw

here's what i'd like to do:

I've got a ***ref*** that represents a list of items. I'd like to have a ***listbox*** (seesaw?) that displays this lists contents, updating automatically (whenever i change the ref).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [add-watch](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/add-watch) to add callback which will be called every time ref is modified. This callback should call method that updates listbox:

```
(def data (ref [1 2 3]))

(defn list-model 
  "Create list model based on collection"
  [items]
  (let [model (javax.swing.DefaultListModel.)]
    (doseq [item items] (.addElement model item))
    model))

(def listbox (seesaw.core/listbox :model [])) 

(add-watch data nil
  (fn [_ _ _ items] (.setModel listbox (list-model items))))
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do it is to bind the contents of the ref to the model of the listbox, using seesaw.bind.

```
(require [seesaw core [bind :as b]])
(def lb (listbox))
(def r (ref []))
(b/bind r (b/property lb :model))
```

The seesaw.bind library is well worth exploring, IMHO. The [API](http://daveray.github.com/seesaw/seesaw.bind-api.html) is well documented once you have some idea how it all fits together; [this blog post](http://blog.darevay.com/2011/07/seesaw-widget-binding/) is a nice introduction.